# Performance of selecting random pixels

Tags: image, image-processing, rust

I'm starting out with Rust and coming from a much higher level language some stuff is pretty new to me. I'm trying to select a random black pixel from an image and fill it white. Continue until a given part of the image is white. I'm using `image` crate for pixel manipulation.

I made a naive implementation. I create a new vector, iterate over all pixels in the image, select those that are black, then pick a random index from the vector using `rand` crate:

```
fn seed_pixel(img: &RgbImage) -> [u32; 2] {
    let mut empty_pixels: Vec<[u32; 2]> = Vec::new();
    for (x, y, pixel) in img.enumerate_pixels() {
        if pixel[0] == 0 {
            empty_pixels.push([x, y])
        }
    }

    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    return *empty_pixels.choose(&mut rng).unwrap();
}
```

It works, but the efficiency is pretty outrageous. For a bigger image (2000 px x 1000 px) it takes around 0.17s, and as I need to do it multiple times, it adds up pretty quickly. Is there some more efficient method of doing this? Are there any resources I could read about those issues?

Comment: Quick question: Are you running in release mode (`cargo run ---release`) when measuring speed?

Comment: How are you measuring?

Comment: @Caesar
Damn, I feel stupid, indeed an optimized build it is ~10ms. Not great, not terrible. I guess that concludes it.

Comment: I think the algorithm is the "problem", not rust. you are generating a list of pixel coordinates... repeatedly (assuming you call the function repeatedly). -- need to keep them in a *set*, not a list (or at least formulate removal from the list as moving the last element into the gap left by the removed element). removal needs to be O(1). and you need to build that list once, not repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ChristophRackwitz already made one suggestion (keep a `HashSet` of the black pixels, only compute that once), I'd like to add three:

- If you're bucket filling adjacent pixels, don't add a pixel if the pixel to its left is also black
- Don't generate a list of all black pixels, but start at a random position in the image and search for the next black pixel from there (but make sure to search in the same order as `enumerate_pixels` would return the pixels - making sure the image access is a linear memory scan)
- Don't generate a list of pixels, but remember only one pixel. Whenever you encounter a black pixel, replace the remembered pixel by the found pixel with probability `1 / number_of_found_black_pixels`.

The first two ideas change which pixels are more/less likely to be selected (the fist favours tall areas of black over wide areas, the second favours black pixels that follow long stretches of non-black pixels), so you'd need to be OK with that.

You'll need to benchmark yourself which of these is a good idea, and whether your `seed_pixel` function is actually the core of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, those are actually excellent suggestions!